# how to generate random one indefenitly till it respects a condition in Java?

Tags: java, random, conditional-statements, generate

Do you have an idea how to generate a random Object until an object doesn't respect a condition ?

I tried like this :

```
//Btw getTeam1() is a hashMap of Integer,Fighter (a type of objects that I use)
//randomIndex
Object randomName = this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray().length)];
while(this.getTeam1().get(randomName).dontVerifyMyConditionBlabla) {
        randomName = this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray().length)];
}
```

But apparently, it doesn't sound good. Any advice ?

Comment: Rather than possibly re-pick the same objects multiple times, simply shuffle the array and try objects in order until you find you want one or find none

Comment: Please, can you write even in "word-code" how do you do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

try `do-while` loop

```
verifyMyCondition(){
   //proccess and return true or false
}

do
{
     randomName = this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(this.getTeam1().keySet().toArray().length)];
}while(verifyMyConditionthis.getTeam1().get(randomName)))
```